# Remote access to PowerPC Leopard Server

Tags: remote-control, osx-server

I have a PowerMac G4 at my office running Leopard Server that I'd like to be able to access remotely. Normally, I'd just use VNC / SSH, but it's behind a router that I don't have admin access over (it's in the office next door and we're in a piggybacking agreement, I just don't feel like asking him to forward ports, etc). I think "Back To My Mac" generally can take care of this, but it's going away and you can't subscribe to MobileMe anymore anyhow.

Is there any software out there that can either UPnP it's way around this situation or somehow create an outbound connection? I suppose it being a PowerPC throws a wrench into the plan also.

Comment: The MobileMe to iCloud FAQ shows that "Back To My Mac" is going to be kept, but there's no guarantee it will work on G4 or Leopard. I'm still using it and really like how terminal and iTerm show all the macs with my mobile me credentials just like apple's screen sharing does. You are correct that it's temporarily unavailable for new signups. :-( it's a really good solution for me still.

Answer (score 1):

Try [PortMap](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/portmap/) -- it's free, universal binary (PPC and Intel), and supports a variety of routers.  Just have it map ports 22 (SSH) and 5900 (VNC).  Note: I'd recommend  using nonstandard public ports, to cut down on the number of password-guessing scans you'll get, and also making sure you don't have any accounts with easy-to-guess passwords (because you'll still get a few scans, no matter how creative you are with port numbers).

Answer (score 0):

I've been using LogMeIn.com for all my remote Mac access. Works amazingly well. Totally free for basic use. No router or firewall changes are necessary.

Piko